# Shannon-fano coding algorithm - strange behaviour on larger sets

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am writing a Shannon-fano algorithm, and I am struggling to find a mistake in my program - my program works for examples I managed to find on internet - example: 
[image]

This is my example with 10 characters, where it sets characters will lower possibilities longer codes:


[image]

On the left side are byte values, middle is possibility and left is the generated code. Why is `65` and `226's` code longer then `0,3` and `32's`? Can anybody see a bug in code?

EDIT: code hidden, because this question was about a school assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not a bug in your code but rather illustrates an inherent weakness in Shannon-Fano codes compared to, say, Huffman compression.

As you know, the Shannon-Fano technique is to sort the list of code frequencies in descending order and then assign a binary symbol (zero or one) to each half of the frequency range. This process is repeated in a recursive fashion as long as there is more than one element in a segment.

This has a weakness, though: While it's true that the more frequent symbols, when grouped together, will have a shorter encoding *on average* than the less frequent symbols, it is not necessarily the case for each and every symbol that it gets a shorter encoding assigned to it.

For more information, see [a question I posted a while back over on Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/32831/shannon-fano-puzzle) about this very issue.